# I need a foolproof checklist for hosting an already built e-commerce site on Amazon Web Services

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have built an e-commerce website on my local computer that uses Django version 2.2 and python 3.7.

The website consists of:

[image: main directory view]

fancyfetish is the main project directory.
The apps, (cart, users, baseapp, products, blog) are all stored in their own directory 'apps.

[image: project and apps directory view]

Within the settings folder I have three settings files:
- production.py
- base.py
- development.py

[image: static files view]

The static file in the main directory is where I put collectstatic files.
Media is where I store externally uploaded images (product images for example)
Docs is just random bits like a hand drawn site layout. 
Static files like JS and CSS are stored within baseapp, within apps.

I want to host this website on Amazon Web Services, and I assume I need to use Elastic Beanstalk. I went through the process of trying to host with free version of EB, installed the EB CLI, and after using eb create and eb deploy on the CLI my website appeared.

However, the static files didn't load properly in the first instance because I had not properly configured DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. I have now done this. But before deploying I added eb migrate functionality so that I could also migrate my database.

[image]

This seems to have messed everything up. I can no longer deploy because there is a DATABASE error, which I expected. The error said 'Not able to connect to MySQL database through 'localhost'. Well, of course it cant.

So, in order to deploy my site on AWS I needed to configure the databases, because with the eb migrate functionality it will no longer deploy without trying to also connect to my database using the settings I have configured.

I have so far, whilst in development mode, connected my project to MySQL and everything is running perfectly on localhost, with my models transferring beautifully to the database just as I would like.

I worked out that I need to create a database on AWS, obviously. So I set up an RDS. I didn't link it to my deployed application because it would appear that the application doesn't have an environment that I can see when I log into my console. So where my project has been deploying to I don't know, because it doesn't look like the CLI version is connected to the online version in my console.

So I thought I'd deal with that problem later and work out how to make a database, which I managed to do. However, migrating the database I already have up and running on MySQL to my RDS database seems impossible, and there are not very good instructions. Let alone trying to then connect said database to my deployed application, which doesn't seem to sync with my local app.

So, I have ended up deleting everything because I was becoming so confused, with so many new directories (.ebextensions etc etc) and a database that wont connect, a project that won't deploy, a database that wont point to my project etc. I ended up created an EC2 folder and all sorts, getting myself massively confused with what I actually need to do to make this whole thing work.

If any part of this ramble makes any sense to *anyone* out there, and you yourself have managed to deploy a larger django project to AWS and keep your existing databases then please do let me know. But I have a feeling this may be a long shot.

Basically I need a step by step list of what to do to deploy:

For example:
    1) Create an elastic beanstalk instance
    2) Create an environment on CLI that syncs to the one in my AWS console
    etc
    etc

(With how to's if you possibly have the time!)

Thank you, and I am so sorry for being so confused by something that may be simple

Edited to show my process:
I have built a directory called .ebextensions with a file within it called django.config with the following content:

```
option_settings:
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
  WSGIPath: fancyfetish/wsgi.py
```

I have run the following command:

```
eb init -p python-3.6 fancyfetish
```

There was no output as a result of this in the terminal, however a directory was created called .elasticbeanstalk with one file in it called config.yml

[image]

I then typed eb init to create an SSH key pair and there was no output from this command at all:

[image]

As you can see I have tried doing this several times.

Instead I created a key pair manually within AWS console and a file automatically to my computer called keyname.pem

I then typed into the console

```
chmon 400 path/to/key/keyname.pem
```

This provided no output on the terminal so I cannot know if it worked.

I moved the downloaded SSH file into the .SSH directory in the Home directory of my computer, and then in the terminal typed:

```
eb init -k nameofkey
```

The output was:

WARNING: Uploaded SSH public key for "fancyfet" into EC2 for region us- 
   west-2.

I then went on to type

```
eb create fancyfet-env
```

And an environment was created with the following output:

[image]

I know that this has to do with databases and connecting to MySQL.

I then typed:

```
eb deploy
```

With the following output:

[image]

So now comes the bit where I get stuck, successfully creating a database that connects to my already existing database that is populated with database in MySQL, and connecting the project to the database.

HELP!(Thank you so much!)

Comment: did you get a chance to look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: We have a number of Django apps deployed with multiple environments on AWS. Have you followed the tutorial for deploying that @ArunmainthanKamalanathan mentioned? If so, what specific error/block are you facing?

Comment: Yes I have followed that tutorial to the T. The issues arise when trying to connect to the database, it fails to connect. I am trying to work out if it is something to do with VPC. Also I need to work out how to place the database I already have running with MySQL on localhost, into my online AWS application, however it recommends 'keeping them separate' so when you eb terminate it doesnt delete the database. I am going to go through the whole process again today from the beginning and make note of each error and issue I face.